# Should we cache the augmented data

Tags: tensorflow, caching, deep-learning, image-classification, data-augmentation

I suddenly wonder, in terms of accuracy on new data, should we cache the augmented data or no (on data pipeline)

I don't think caching the augmented data is a good idea, if we're not caching it makes the data passed thru the model become more diverse. Am i wrong? if so please tell me why :>

(Im sorry for asking such a simple question on this site because i dont really have any friend that can answer my curiousity)